# Ember component in component

Tags: ember.js

I was wondering if wrapping components in components is effective in the way I hope it is.

Basically I created a few components, from other plugins, ie easy pie charts and full calendar, and wish to wrap them into jarvi smart widgets, which would also be components. But, how do I tell the jarvis-widget component what to render insert inside it? So if in a template I have:

```
{{jarvis-widget-component}}// here I want the full-Calendar component
{{jarvis-widget-component}}// here I want 3 small easy-pies
{{jarvis-widget-component}}// here I want 2 easy pies, but to pass them color and size attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 templates, one for each layout.

- full-calendar
- three-pies
- two-pies

Then you can pass a name property to the component:

```
{{jarvis-widget-component layoutName='full-calendar'}}
{{jarvis-widget-component layoutName='three-pies'}}
{{jarvis-widget-component layoutName='two-pies'}}
```

I don't know jarvis components, but that is the general idea.